# How to store an image path to the table?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a database with a column for image location. In my WordPress, under my themes folder I have following

- themes

  - my-theme
  - assets

    - images

I have added few images here. But I have no idea about path location to be stored in the database column.

Can anybody please help me on that?

Comment: Why do you need to read those paths from the DB? Why are these assets in the themes folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I recommend to have all of your theme assets in theme folder itself, not next to it. In order to do it, create assets folder inside your template, and put all your images, scripts, fonts and etc there. After that in your template code files try to put this code in the template file where you want to locate to the template image:

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/assets/images/IMAGE_NAME_HERE" alt="IMAGE ALT TEXT" ?>
```

Comment: Thanks I already fixed it. I used the same way you answered.